# 'import cv2' works fine in spyder and in command prompt BUT gives error when a program is run from Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, opencv, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to use opencv in my code. It works fine when I run it directly from spyder or from command prompt using `import cv2`.
I have a small code in file 'test_opencv_installation.py' that contains `import cv2` as following

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("logo.png")

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("OpenCV logo", image)

cv2.imshow("OpenCV logo gray format", gray_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, The following error occurred when running the file `"C:\Anaconda\envs\my_opencv\test_opencv_installation.py"`:

```
The module 'cv2' could not be found or imported.
```

This is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\my_opencv\test_opencv_installation.py", line 6, in <module>
import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khzG9.png)

Please share your experience and kindly suggest me any solution to this.
Thanks....

Comment: Didn't you install opencv_contrib or python-opencv?

Comment: I did install but  the error persists. As you can see in the image that the import cv2 works well inline with the anaconda prompt.

Comment: You will,have to uninstall and  reinstall again